# GeoTIFF to ndarray

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff

What is the most elegant way to import a multi-band GeoTIFF as a ndarray using Python?  The most common approach I've seen is as follows:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
arys = []
ds = gdal.Open('sample.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
for i in xrange(1, ds.RasterCount+1):
    arys.append(ds.GetRasterBand(i).ReadAsArray())
```

Taken from:  https://cynici.wordpress.com/2011/08/26/geotiff-and-python-gdal/

But it I want to import multiple multiband GeoTiffs, this makes for some messy code.

Comment: Look at [Python GDAL/OGR Cookbook: rasters](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/raster_layers.html) or use [rasterio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rasterio/0.17.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [gdal.Dataset](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal.Dataset-class.html) class also has a ReadAsArray method which will read multiband  rasters into an ndarray.

For example:

```
>>> ds=gdal.Open('multiband.tif')  
>>> print ds.RasterCount, ds.RasterYSize, ds.RasterXSize
4 256 256
>>> nda=ds.ReadAsArray()
>>> print nda.shape
(4, 256, 256)
```

Note: the code in your question is not creating an ndarray, but a list of 2D arrays. To stack the band arrays, you could use something like:

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
ds = gdal.Open('sample.tif', gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
arys=[]
for i in xrange(1, ds.RasterCount+1):
    arys.append(ds.GetRasterBand(i).ReadAsArray())
arys = np.concatenate(arys)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio):

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('sample.tif') as r:
    ar = r.read()
```

The `ar` array has 3-dimensions [band, row, col]

Comment: Can't beat this (if I say so myself)!